# Remove Linkedin info from contacts

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I've recently purchased a Samsung Galaxy S6 and I've noticed that in the contacts there is a section with information taken from Linkedin, even though I haven't let the Linkedin app sync its contacts or download contacts.

[image: Example of Linkedin info in contact]

It doesn't bother me much to have someone's company and position listed there, but with some contacts I get a list of empty boxes, that keeps growing with time (I guess it has to do with those people's privacy setting in Linkedin):

[image: Ever-growing empty linkedin info]

So, is there any way to remove this info, other than uninstalling the Linkedin app?

Comment: I've tried deleting the account from the phone, which seemd to work, but it gets added again when I open the Linkedin app, and the info appears again.

Comment: It also remove the LinkedIn links from any contact details if you uninstall the LinkedIn app and then you can reinstall it again.
Also I have seen such a link like in your picture....but I'm not sure how this was added since it was pointing to a different person. Do you have any ideea how that links are inserted to contacts? 10x

Answer (score 0):

Try going into your contacts,

under settings -- > contacts --> contacts to display

and select your google account instead of All Contacts. You can even setup a custom list of contacts to display that doesn't include LinkedIn.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have selected a custom list, and linkedin is not selected. Also, supposedly linkedin contacts are not synced.